# docker-compose override application properties

Tags: variables, overriding, docker-compose

Having a Spring Boot application we are using application.yml file to store properties. I got a task to give a user a possibility to override some properties while starting an application. Taking into consideration we have dockerised our app docker-compose file is the very right place I believe for that. I found one option which works actually, env_file:

```
backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file:
      - backend/custom.env
    volumes:
      - ../m2_repo:/root/.m2/
      - ../{APP_NAME}/data_sources:/backend/data_sources/
    links:
      - database
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - backend
```

This solves perfectly my task and all the KEY=VALUE pairs override existing in application.yml properties. However, I have 2 questions:

1. It appeared that having multiple services in my docker-compose file I need specify a separate env_file for each service, which is probably not very convenient. Is there a possibility to have one common env_file for the whole docker-compose file?
2. I know that for docker-compose run command there is an option -e where i can put key=value pairs of env variables. Is there any similar option for docker-compose up? I mean in order not to use env_file at all.

Comment: Why is 1) a problem? Do all your Services require the same properties? Are there no overlappings if you use one common env_file?

Comment: It's not a problem, rather I'm looking for an option. My properties are not overlapping, that's actually why I consider having a single env_file rather than multiple files (one for each service)

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1: It is not possible. I also believe it is intentional - to make the developer define what container has access to what `.env` data.

Ad 2: No, you cannot supply the variables using a runtime parameter of `up` command of `docker-compose` (run `docker-compose help up` to see the available runtime params). But you can define these using `environment` clause from within a compose file, like:

```yaml
restart: always
ports:
  - 3000:3000
env_file:
  - backend/custom.env
environment:
  - DB_PASSWORD          # <= #1
  - APP_ENV=production   # <= #2
```

ie.

1. **either just a name** of the env var - its value is then taken from the host machine
2. **or the whole definition** to create a new one to be available within a container

See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) on `environment` clause for more clarification.

Another thing you can do in order to override some settings is to `extend` the compose file using a "parent" one. [Docs on `extends` clause](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#extends)

Unfortunately as of now, `extends` won't work when using compose file of version 3, but it is being discussed in this [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101), so hopefully it will be available soon:)